# Beginner Python question, issue using "or" and "if" together

Tags: python

I am using Python to create a very basic calculator. for whatever reason the numbers will only add - they will not do any of the other functions. Please help!

```
equation_type = input("What kind of math do you want to do? ")
equation_type = equation_type.lower()

first_number = float(input("What is the first number? "))
second_number = float(input("What is the 2nd number? "))

if equation_type == "add" or "addition":
        result = first_number + second_number
elif equation_type == "subtract" or "subtraction":
        result = (first_number - second_number)
elif equation_type == "multiply" or "multiplication":
        result = first_number * second_number
elif equation_type == "divide" or "division":
        result = first_number / second_number
else:
        print("not a valid entry :/")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equation_type == "add" or "addition"` does not do what you think it does.

It's tempting to read Python code as if it were English. It is not! Python is still a programming language, and programming languages have strict rules.

The expression `equation_type == "add" or "addition"` is parsed as `(equation_type == "add") or "addition"`. The first part, `(equation_type == "add")` might be true or false depending on the user's input. However, the second part `"addition"` is *always true* from the perspective of `if`.

Therefore Python always uses the first branch in your `if`/`elif`/`else` chain, and ignores the others, because the first branch is always "true" from its perspective!

The `or` operator has only one purpose: it combines expressions using [logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction). It does not repeatedly apply an equality check for multiple values! Refer to [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) for details on what operators like `or` and `and` can and cannot do.

You probably wanted to write `if equation_type in ("add", "addition"):`. The `in` operator checks whether a value is an element of some collection:

```py
x = "apple"

if x in ("carrot", "celery"):
    print("vegetable")
elif x in ("apple", "pear"):
    print("fruit")
```

The `in` operator works on all kinds of collections: tuples `(a, b, c)`, lists `[a, b, c]`, and the *keys* (not values!) of dictionaries `{a: 1, b: 2}`.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions should be like (one of many ways of doing it):

`equation_type == "add" or equation_type == "addition":`

When checking multiple conditions you need to repeat the equality. There are other ways but since you are in a beginner course you should try to make this one work.

Do the same with the other conditions and see if it works.